# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting below error, although in my POJO classes I have taken Date datatype.

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

LatestReportDatesItem (Pojo class) - Datatype of date variable is Date.
Dao - I am firing query then printing the list.

After that, it is throwing an error while executing for loop.

Someone, Please clarify.

Comment: Posst the code.

Comment: The error is extremely clear. It literally tells you that you cannot cast Timestamp to an Object.

Comment: How can that happen? I may be exposing my ignorance here, but wouldn't any object be compatible with `Object`?

Comment: @MatthewKerian - When I post the code, it says your post is mostly code. Please add some details. I am not able to post the code.

Comment: @Frontear - Same thing is working for other methods but in one method it's throwing this error, although i have tried to convert it to Timestamp but still it did not work.

Comment: @ernest_k Think about it, all classes extend the Object, but that doesn't mean the reverse is true. I could, for example, do `Object num = 13` and get away with it, however I cannot do `int num = (Object)13;`.

Comment: @AyushGoyal Please only post the code which is causing the error, not everything.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take a look around and see how to ask a proper question, to increase the chances to gave some good answers from the community: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, stackoverflow.com/tour. For example, could you please show your efforts and paste a snippet of your code?

Comment: @Frontear That would be a compile error, not a class cast exception. But `(Object) anyTimeStampObjectHere` should work, as `TimeStamp` is a subclass of `Object`

Comment: @ernest_k agreed, but honestly, unless OP posts code, we will literally never know what they've done to cause the error.

Comment: Can you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Updated the post with attached image.

Comment: I believe the `ClassCastException` is trying to say that you cannot cast to *an array of `Object`*. Isn’t that a square bracket before `L`? Can you paste the stacktrace into the question, formatted as code? And if you would have any chance of finding the code line where it happens, perhaps??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you're showing the error, we see it's not `java.lang.Object`, but `[Ljava.lang.Object;`, which is `Object[]` in Java.
Because you're only selecting one column, you're not getting a list of Object[], but instead you're getting a list of the type of that column, which in this case is Timestamp.

Just replace the type

```
List<Timestamp> list = (List<Timestamp>) entityManager.createQuery(...
```